# I want to show the Price of products through API in mageno2

Tags: magento2, price, rest-api, soap-api

I want to show the prices of the product which will come through API.This prices are not stored in magento database. I just want to know how can it be achieved with just explanation.

Comment: So you have a third party API which stores the prices of your products and you want to show the prices in your magento store. I think you should sync your prices with magento using a micro service. It can update magento's prices through the mage rest api.
Otherwise, if you just change the frontend to display the prices from your third party api, magento won't know about the prices and the e-mails, invoices..etc will all have invalid prices.

Comment: What is the final solution to this issue? Is it possible, in magento, to update product price by querying a third party api? I am trying to develop an app where the product's price needs to be shown by querying a third party api, every time.